# Global.asax Event: Application_OnPostAuthenticateRequest

Tags: authentication, asp.net-2.0

I am using `Application_OnPostAuthenticateRequest` event in `global.asax` to get

**a)** Roles and permissions of authenticated user also i have made my custom principal class to get user detail and roles and permission.

**b)** To get some information which remain same for that user.

```
void Application_OnPostAuthenticateRequest(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    // Get a reference to the current User
    IPrincipal objIPrincipal = HttpContext.Current.User;

    // If we are dealing with an authenticated forms authentication request
    if ((objIPrincipal.Identity.IsAuthenticated) && (objIPrincipal.Identity.AuthenticationType == "Forms"))
    {
        CustomPrincipal objCustomPrincipal = new CustomPrincipal();
        objCustomPrincipal = objCustomPrincipal.GetCustomPrincipalObject(objIPrincipal.Identity.Name);
        HttpContext.Current.User = objCustomPrincipal;
        CustomIdentity ci = (CustomIdentity)objCustomPrincipal.Identity;
        HttpContext.Current.Cache["CountryID"] = FatchMasterInfo.GetCountryID(ci.CultureId);
        HttpContext.Current.Cache["WeatherLocationID"] = FatchMasterInfo.GetWeatherLocationId(ci.UserId);
        Thread.CurrentPrincipal = objCustomPrincipal;
    }
}
```

My question is the following:

1. This event fires every time for every request. Hence for each request the code execute?
2. My approach is right or not?
3. Is it right to add HttpContext.Current.Cache in this event or we should move it to Session_Start

Answer (score 4):

1. Yes this event fires for every request
2. Yes you can use this event to get information for the authenticated user
3. No, **don't use** `HttpCurrent.Current.Cache` to store user specific information as the cache is common for all users and you will get conflicts. Use `HttpContext.Current.Session` instead as this will be specific to the user.

Comment: Thnaks,
Again few doubdt raise?

If this event fires for every request then for each request my connection to database for roles and permition executes. Is it good, can't we do same in session start event.

Comment: Yes, it would be better to use the SessionStart event as it is executed once per user session and you can store user specific information inside the Session object.

Comment: If we move all code from Application_OnPostAuthenticateRequest() to Session_Start()

then what is the use of Application_OnPostAuthenticateRequest()

Comment: @DarinDimitrov Darin , wouldn't it be better to store on a cache via `dictionary<UserID , UserInfo>` alike ?

Comment: @RoyiNamir, no, it wouldn't. How would you handle things like automatic expiration when memory usage reaches low levels with a Dictionary?

Comment: @DarinDimitrov tnx for reply. indeed how ? session would also have this problem ....?

Comment: @RoyiNamir, yes of course that it will have those problems. Might consider using a cookie vector pointing to a centralized server side cache such as memcached or Redis.

Comment: oh  , you mean DO store in cache but as a regular key ? ( which i can attach expirtaion) ? ( redis or something)

Comment: @RoyiNamir, in-memory cache is not adapted to webfarm scenarios where your application is running in more than 1 node. Consider using a distributed cache for this purpose.