# Application_OnPostAuthenticateRequest and Custom Principal Caching

Tags: c#, session

I have implemented a custom principal approach as outlined [here](http://www.asp.net/web-forms/tutorials/security/introduction/forms-authentication-configuration-and-advanced-topics-cs) under **Step 5: Using a Custom Principal**

I then retrieve the user credentials from the database for use with the custom principal, but this results in a database call for every request, so naturally the answer would be to save my user object somewhere, either Session or Cache.

However, it would appear that `HttpContext.Current.Session` cannot be accessed from within 
`Application_OnPostAuthenticateRequest`, so Cache would seem to be the way to go

The problem is these two answers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1147292/1021958) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6362717/1021958) offer contradictory advice.  The first one advises

> No, don't use HttpCurrent.Current.Cache to store user specific information as the cache is common for all users and you will get conflicts. Use HttpContext.Current.Session instead as this will be specific to the user.

and the second one advises

> Use the Cache instead of session

So which is the preferred method?
If `Session` is the way to go how do I put my user object into the Session object from the `Application_OnPostAuthenticateRequest` method.
If `Cache` is the way forward what problems will I face?  For instance, is there a time limit on items held in the Cache?  (I know to get around potential conflicts by using unique key from User object)

Answer (score 3):

Not sure if your still looking for a answer but the best place to store the authentication information is in the `Ticket.UserData` property when writing the ticket.

I am assuming if you are using a custom provider that you are overriding the `SetAuthCookie` method.

If that is the case then that method will let you pass in the extra information for storing. It's common to store things like friendly username, roles, or other authentication details.

See this link for [Setting UserData in Authentication Cookie](http://www.asp.net/web-forms/tutorials/security/introduction/forms-authentication-configuration-and-advanced-topics-vb)

Comment: If your application is using Windows Authentication, there is no ticket.